# How to display PDF or Word's DOC/DOCX inside WinForms window?

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-word

I'm wondering what's the best option to display a pdf/doc document inside form in my c# winforms app.

This control should only allow do display preview. Edtiting documents should be forbidden.

I'm looking for free solution.

The best option would be to attach a few separate *.dlls to solution but it's not a requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using the preview handlers for Vista, Windows 7. 
I used the code provided by Brad Smith (with corrections from the comments).

http://www.brad-smith.info/blog/archives/79 - Hosting Preview Handlers in Windows Forms Applications

Answer (score 0):

An often suggested solution is to use a webbrowser component inside the form that views the PDF:
[MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winforms/thread/b8c7a504-562f-4424-9ac3-bda3c640ca86/)

Another approach is to use an ActiveX Control included with the Adobe Acrobat Reader but therefore you need a license from Adobe.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Preview Handlers. There is a [WPF Article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/wpf_vista_preview_handler.aspx) over at CodeProject, which should be dead easy to translate to WinForms if you need it.