# Previewing .doc, .docx in C# Windows Forms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, ms-word

I'm developing a windows forms project in c#. For now I can preview .PDF files with WebBrowser tool in ToolBox but that doesn't preview .DOC or .DOCX; instead it opens up a prompt ask either you want to save it or open in just like IE does. 
Now what I want is simply a preview of a .DOC or .DOCX. I tried this with Office.Interop assemblies but didn't help. I checked tens of websites and found one but iink was broken and also there were only reading from a .DOC nohing else. Is there any tool or way to implement this?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you be sure word will be installed or do you want a solution independent of word? (i.e. do you want to embed a word pane to view the file or do you need to parse and render it yourself?)

Comment: As I said above, I'm now using .PDF with webBrowser tool in VS; it works perfectly, but it doesn't render .DOC or .DOCX. Well, I may embed a word pane to my form which I don't know how to do; anything possible, I'm ready to try...

Comment: For what you are trying to do, this is normal behavior. Since webbrowser can render pdf but no MSOFFICE files. I think, actually i'm sure, you'll need a plugin/lib to do this. I don't know wich one but try google. Something like [this](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/user-interface-edition/windows-forms?_kk=WinForms&_kt=7c265863-a1ee-4461-8edf-473f4d42f77f&gclid=CK7rqaqX76sCFUEY4QodD1Oeew)

Comment: It has already been asked.
[Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/511046/how-to-display-pdf-or-words-doc-docx-inside-winforms-window) Link was dead on the page but [this works](http://codinglight.blogspot.com/2008/10/simple-docbrowser-control.html)

Comment: Yes, link was broken on the page but this looks like what I need; thank you Frederiek!

Comment: I wanna give you a reputation, could you post the link as an Answer or how should I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Word Control for .NET](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/winwordcontrol.aspx) is good article, even it seems dated but it's still work with MS Word 2010 and .NET 4.0

Comment: Link is dead...

Answer (score 1):

This guy has a [PreviewHandler](https://www.brad-smith.info/blog/archives/79) for Winforms. Works like a charm!