# Preview pane for Microsoft Office files - VB.net

Tags: vb.net, ms-office

I have a treeview control based on the file system and I would like to implement functionality exactly like windows file explorer whereby a user can click on a file and it would display a preview in the preview windows/pane

I have already managed to do this for files such as images and PDF's with a web browser control but I'm struggling with Office files (xlsx, docx, pptx) as it opens the files in their respective applications rather than the preview window.

I've seen quite a few articles like this but can't find a working, or even semi-working example! Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you'll at least need to show us your existing code and point out where the problem starts to occur.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to display PDF or Word's DOC/DOCX inside WinForms window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/511046/how-to-display-pdf-or-words-doc-docx-inside-winforms-window)